# Save a SVG click location and recreate it on reload

Tags: javascript, svg, snap.svg

I am new to working with SVG's, and I'm struggling with part of a project.
I'm trying to save a user's click location on a scalable/pannable svg so I can recreate it from that point forward when I load the page.

I'm using snap.svg and snap.svg.zpd because I had seen them used in an example when I started this project.

(this part is working)
The user can zoom/pan the svg and place a marker on the the image using a mouse click.

html:

```
 <svg id="svgmap" width="695" height="900" ></svg>
```

js:

```
var mySvg = $("#svgmap")[0];
var snap = Snap("#svgmap");

var imageMap = snap.image("mySvgUrl", 10, 10, 695, 900);
var group = snap.group(imageMap);

var pt = mySvg.createSVGPoint(); 

imageMap.click(function (evt) {

pt.x = evt.clientX;
pt.y = evt.clientY; 

//find the coordinates within the svg
var transformed = pt.matrixTransform(mySvg.getScreenCTM().inverse());

//place marker 
var marker = snap.image("myMarkerUrl", transformed.x, transformed.y, 8, 8)
group.add(marker);
});
```

(This part doesn't work.)
I want to save the location of the user's click so I can recreate the marker's location the next time I load the page. 
I can't recreate the location when the page reloads.

I've approached the problem by changing the values that I save
(x/y coordinates of the user click, transformed coordinates, and even attempted percentages of the view area in a fit of desperation), and by changing the way that I transform the coordinates for the reloaded svg.
I think this is as close as I've came to getting it right.

```
var pt = mySvg.createSVGPoint();
pt.x = mySavedX;
pt.y = mySavedY;

var recreatedPoint = pt.matrixTransform(mySvg.getScreenCTM())

var marker = snap.image("myImageURL", recreatedPoint.x, recreatedPoint.Y, 4, 4)
    group.add(marker);

//center the marker and zoom-in
    var zoomscale = 3; 
     mySvg.firstElementChild.setAttribute("transform", "translate(" + (1-3)*recreatedPoint.x  + "," + (1-3)*recreatedPoint.y + "), scale(" + zoomscale + "," + zoomscale + ")");
```

How do I recreate the location of a previous scaled/panned SVG click the next time I load the page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The transformed points that you generate for the marker in step 1 are the ones you want to save.  Ie. `transformed.x` and `transformed.y`.  What you were doing there was converting the screen space coordinates of the click, to SVG user space coordinates.

Those SVG coordinates are now independent of how the SVG is zoomed and/or panned.  Just use those coordinates. Place your marker there.  You shouldn't need to do any further transformations.

```
var marker = snap.image("myMarkerUrl", mySavedX, mySavedY, 8, 8)
group.add(marker);
```